# How to Build the same class from both base and derived class using generics in java

Tags: java, spring, generics

Having fetched data from database, and mapped to two POJO, I want to create the same object with these two POJO using generics:

```
public class BaseObj {

  String baseVar;
}

public class DerivedObj extends BaseObj {

  String derivedVar;
}
// getter setter omitted
```

I wish to use both `baseVar` and `derivedVar` values to form the same object:

```
public class MyObject {

  String myBaseVar;
  String myChildVar; 
}
// getter setter omitted
```

How to create a generic method, that can take both base class and derived class, and create MyObject? So far I have tried:

```
static <T extends BaseObj> MyObject buildObj(T obj) {
  MyObject myObj = new MyObject();

  myObj.setMyBaseVar(obj.getBaseVar());

  // ⬇⬇⬇ The method getDerivedVar() is undefined for the type T ⬇⬇⬇
  myObj.setMyChildVar(obj.getDerivedVar()); 
  // Clearly it can't infer getDerivedVar from base class

  return myObj;
}
```

When building myObject from base class, the `childVal` should be null, but it should be getting value from child object.

This is a simplified version, MyObject is a deeply nested one. Is it possible to do that? Since my situation is getting db data mapped to POJO, and these data are related to each other, or is there other way that I'm missing?

[Sandbox here](https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/java-main-IUXHfB)

Comment: Without casting the `obj` parameter to the `DerivedObj`, you can't access its `derivedVar` property. If you are finding yourself writing a lot of these boilerplate mapper classes, consider using a mapper generator tool like MapStruct: https://mapstruct.org/

Comment: Wow, I didn't know such tool exist, thank you for the recommendation! It looks so sweet and easy to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ugly workaround with casting:

```
  public static <T extends BaseObj> MyObject buildObj(T obj) {
    if (obj.getClass().equals(DerivedObj.class)) {
      DerivedObj derivedObj = (DerivedObj) obj; // casting to DerivedObj class

      return new MyObject(obj.getBaseVar(), derivedObj.getDerivedVar());
    }

    return new MyObject(obj.getBaseVar(), null);
  }
```